# Copying elements from an array to a diferent type

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I have created a class named Card and on another class named River I have created a String array.I want to copy the elements of the String array on a new Card type aray in my River class. How can I do that? I have tried arrays.copyOf() and "array".clone() but I get the error that it can't convert from String type to Card type

Well, I my Card class is this.It holds information about a card (I am trying to make a blackjack game) and I have a String array with all the numbers and figures ( "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K") and I want to copy them in a new class with array type Card

```
    import java.lang.Integer;
    class Card
    {
    private String card;
    private int cardvalue;
    private Card(String card)
    {
        this.card = card;
    }
    private int getValue()
    {
        if (card.equals("J") || card.equals("Q") || card.equals("K"))
        {
           cardvalue = 10;
           return cardvalue;
         }
         else if (card.equals("A"))
         { 
             cardvalue =1;
             return cardvalue;
         }
         else if (card.equals("2") ||card.equals("3") || card.equals("4") || 
                  card.equals("5") ||card.equals("6") || card.equals("7") || 
                  card.equals("8") || card.equals("9") || card.equals("10"))   
         {
             cardvalue = Integer.valueOf(card);
             return cardvalue;
         }
         return cardvalue;
     }
     private boolean isAce()
     {
         if (cardvalue == 1)
         {
             return true;
         }
         else if (cardvalue == 11)
         {
            return true;
         }
         else
         {
            return false;
         }
    }
    private boolean equals()
    {
       if (card.equals(card))
       {
          return true;
       }  
       else
       {
         return false;
       } 
    }
    public String toString()
    {
       return card;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're going to need to post some code.

Comment: refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how ask good question

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert any primitive type to user defined type directly. It would be helpful if you show some code.

Comment: Like from string to Card type but this work can be done indirectly

Comment: I can't find a way to do it indirectly that's my problem

Comment: It would be help if you state, why you are copying string array to card, what actually you what to done?

Comment: My String array is a static array and my Card array is where all the other modifications occur